# Spree Commerce extending helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decorator, spree

I am attempting to extend one of the helper modules which Spree Commerce offers. I came across the following file: `spree/frontend/app/helpers/frontend_helper.rb`

Ultimately what I am trying to do is add a simple helper method to this module. I plan to call this helper method for use with the single product page. My implementation seems to be working fine with a couple exceptions, which has led me to believe that I have screwed up somewhere. Here is what I have done:

I have the file app/helpers/spree/frontend_helper_decorator.rb. The contents of this file:

```
Spree::FrontendHelper.module_eval do

    # Create Variant Matrix
    def create_variant_matrix( variants )

        @valid_variants = {}

        ...

        @valid_variants

    end

end
```

The next thing I have done is extended the Products Controller for the purpose of overwriting one of the methods. I created `app/controllers/spree/products_controller_decorator.rb`. The content of this file:

```
Spree::ProductsController.class_eval do
    include Spree::FrontendHelper

    # Overwrite Show to include variant matrix
    def show

        @variants = @product.variants_including_master.active(current_currency).includes([:option_values, :images])
        @product_properties = @product.product_properties.includes(:property)
        @taxon = Spree::Taxon.find(params[:taxon_id]) if params[:taxon_id]
        @vMatrix = create_variant_matrix( @variants )

    end

end
```

As you can see here, I have overwritten the show method, copied the code from the default spree method and added my custom call. I have also included the `FrontendHelper` module in the controller.

This works without any errors with few exceptions. When I run bundle for the purpose of installing a new gem for instance, I typically get an error which requires me to remove my custom FrontendHelper method completly before I can successfully install the gem. Once the gem is installed, I add the code back in and it works fine. The error I receive is:

```
/fake/path/app/controllers/spree/product_controller_decorator.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Spree::FrontendHelper (NameError)
```

I have tried searching for this error with no luck. I am fairly new to Ruby (background is in PHP), but based on the tutorials I followed, I feel that it is correct. It also seems to be working properly in most scenarios.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Spree are you running? `Spree::FrontendHelper` is a new addition to Spree in master (which will become 3.0). You may be using a stable released version of Spree which does not have `Spree::FrontendHelper`.

Comment: I am using Spree 2.4.2. It's that easy. If you want to answer this questions directly, I will accept it. Thanks!